# Appengine python datastore on local

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, local

I have an appengine application and I would like to download my datastore in order to use the application in local.
How could I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) shows a way to do a backup of your prod Datastore. Use [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_the_Datastore) to do a restore from your dev server.

Looking at it, I also found [this blog post](http://mbrochh.tumblr.com/post/6937702727/importing-google-app-engine-datastore-into-your-local) that seems to show another way for you to do what you want.  I haven't fully tested this yet though.

Comment: Thank you. Can't understand why did they vote down my question.

Comment: I guess the fact it was only 2 lines means they didn't think it proved "enough research has been made".

Comment: Actually I always do it before posting a question.... I cannot find anything about this even on Google. I really need to do this, it's strange that there is not a way

Comment: as I said there IS a way, but I can't seem to find it.....  I remember I saw two lines you could add to your devserver config that lets you do this exact thing without having to backup/restore.  I think I know where I have this website saved.  give me a minute

Comment: using this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_the_Datastore  means you can launch from a file backup, so you can use the link I provided in the answer to create your backup and this method to restore it in your local.

Comment: http://mbrochh.tumblr.com/post/6937702727/importing-google-app-engine-datastore-into-your-local  (or this provides another way... haven't fully tested it myself though)

Comment: Gonna try this!! Thank you!